# Is it possible to create a Realm where everyone has read access, but users can only modify objects that they create?

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

Is it possible to create a realm where everyone has read access, but users can only modify objects that they create?  An example would be a forum where any user can post and all users can see all posts, but only the user who made the post can edit it or delete it.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible.
The permissions for Realms are global to the Realm.

To get your desired behaviour, you would need to use multiple Realms.
Each user has a Realm which they write into.
Users have write permission to their own Realms, and read permissions
to all the others.